# Any way to use MacBook Pro in "dock/clamshell" mode while NOT plugged in?

Tags: closed-clamshell

I use my MBP in clamshell mode most of the time, via a Thunderbolt dock.

But from time to time, it's good to let it run from battery power. However if I unplug the power adapter, I cannot enter clamshell mode unless I open the lid.

Is there any way to enable clamshell mode WITHOUT using power adapter?

Comment: If you're connecting the macbook to an external display, why would you not plug in the power cable?

Comment: I do, most of the time, but it's bad for the battery to be always plugged in. I would like to run off battery for a few hours every few days.